# Excel 2013 64-bit VBA: Clipboard API doesn't work

Tags: vba, winapi, excel, 64-bit, office-2013

I used to be able to use Windows API calls in Excel VBA to set text on the clipboard.  But ever since upgrading to 64-bit Office 2013, I cannot.  Below is some code that does not error, but it is also not setting any text on the clipboard.  Can someone help me test and troubleshoot?

After pasting the code below into a code module in VBA, you can test it in the immediate windows by typing `Clipboard_SetData("Copy this to the clipboard.")` and it should set that text on the clipboard and you would be able to paste it into any other application.

(I am using Windows 8, so I cannot use Microsoft Forms or the Data Object to manipulate the clipboard.  It does not work properly on Windows 8.)

**UPDATE and EDIT:** Code below has been corrected and now works properly in 64-bit Excel, thanks to Jason Kurtz' answer below.  If you find this useful, please vote his answer up.

```
Option Explicit

'Found 64-bit API declarations here: http://spreadsheet1.com/uploads/3/0/6/6/3066620/win32api_ptrsafe.txt
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalAlloc Lib "kernel32" (ByVal wFlags As Long, ByVal dwBytes As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalFree Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalLock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalSize Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalUnlock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function EmptyClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetClipboardData Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Long, ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetClipboardData Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Long) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function lstrcpy Lib "kernel32" (ByVal lpString1 As Any, ByVal lpString2 As Any) As LongPtr

Private Const GMEM_MOVEABLE = &H2
Private Const GMEM_ZEROINIT = &H40
Private Const GHND = (GMEM_MOVEABLE Or GMEM_ZEROINIT)

Public Const CF_TEXT = 1
Public Const MAXSIZE = 4096

Sub ClipBoard_SetData(MyString As String)
'32-bit code by Microsoft: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192913.aspx
    Dim hGlobalMemory As LongPtr, lpGlobalMemory As LongPtr
    Dim hClipMemory As LongPtr, X As Long

    ' Allocate moveable global memory.
    hGlobalMemory = GlobalAlloc(GHND, Len(MyString) + 1)

    ' Lock the block to get a far pointer to this memory.
    lpGlobalMemory = GlobalLock(hGlobalMemory)

    ' Copy the string to this global memory.
    lpGlobalMemory = lstrcpy(lpGlobalMemory, MyString)

    ' Unlock the memory.
    If GlobalUnlock(hGlobalMemory) <> 0 Then
       MsgBox "Could not unlock memory location. Copy aborted."
       'Debug.Print "GlobalFree returned: " & CStr(GlobalFree(hGlobalMemory))
       GoTo OutOfHere
    End If

    ' Open the Clipboard to copy data to.
    If OpenClipboard(0&) = 0 Then
       MsgBox "Could not open the Clipboard. Copy aborted."
       Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Clear the Clipboard.
    X = EmptyClipboard()

    ' Copy the data to the Clipboard.
    hClipMemory = SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, hGlobalMemory)

OutOfHere:
    If CloseClipboard() = 0 Then
       MsgBox "Could not close Clipboard."
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Does the `SetClipboardData()` call succeed? If not, what does `GetLastError()` report?

Comment: Just tried it. Clipboard_SetData("fjdkla;jfd") \ Debug output: \ 
hGlobalMemory is 287253201176 \ 
lpGlobalMemory is 287450358016 \ 
lpGlobalMemory is 287362598488 \ 
hClipMemory is 287253201176 \ 
LastDLLError is 0 \ 
I wonder why lstrcopy returns a different address than GlobalLock.  I investigated the [lstrcopy API page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647490(v=vs.85).aspx) and Microsoft is warning us not to use it.  I wonder if it's being disabled by some kind of Windows 8 security feature.  Anyone know how to use [StringCchCopy](http://bit.ly/15N1jBR) in VBA?

Comment: The mentioned file 'win32api_ptrsafe.txt' can now be downloaded from 'Office 2010 Help Files: Win32API_PtrSafe with 64-bit Support' (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9970)

Comment: As of 12/12/2021, this code works unmodified in Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2111 Build 16.0.14701.20206) 64-bit.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

OK, I got it now...

You need to change this line in your version of the code:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function lstrcpy Lib "kernel32" (ByVal lpString1 As String, ByVal lpString2 As String) As LongPtr
```

To this:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function lstrcpy Lib "kernel32" (ByVal lpString1 As Any, ByVal lpString2 As Any) As LongPtr
```

If you step through the code as you had it, you will see that the value of lpGlobalMemory changes when lstrcopy is called. When the types are changed to Any, the value stays the same.

Works for me on windows 7. Hope it works for you!

Comment: Thanks, this worked: and I note that you're using a pointer as the return type, not a long integer - there's code on other sites using Long or LongLong, which will work just fine until it doesn't.

Answer (score 14):

Posting complete code for others. 
Tested and working on 32 Bit Versions of Excel 2007, 2010, 2013, 2016
and 64 Bit Excel 2013
All running on Windows 10

```
 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14738330/office-2013-excel-putinclipboard-is-different
Option Explicit
#If VBA7 Then
    Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalUnlock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalLock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalAlloc Lib "kernel32" (ByVal wFlags As Long, ByVal dwBytes As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    Declare PtrSafe Function CloseClipboard Lib "User32" () As Long
    Declare PtrSafe Function OpenClipboard Lib "User32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    Declare PtrSafe Function EmptyClipboard Lib "User32" () As Long
    Declare PtrSafe Function lstrcpy Lib "kernel32" (ByVal lpString1 As Any, ByVal lpString2 As Any) As LongPtr
    Declare PtrSafe Function SetClipboardData Lib "User32" (ByVal wFormat As Long, ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As LongPtr
#Else
    Declare Function GlobalUnlock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
    Declare Function GlobalLock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
    Declare Function GlobalAlloc Lib "kernel32" (ByVal wFlags As Long, ByVal dwBytes As Long) As Long
    Declare Function CloseClipboard Lib "User32" () As Long
    Declare Function OpenClipboard Lib "User32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
    Declare Function EmptyClipboard Lib "User32" () As Long
    Declare Function lstrcpy Lib "kernel32" (ByVal lpString1 As Any, ByVal lpString2 As Any) As Long
    Declare Function SetClipboardData Lib "User32" (ByVal wFormat As Long, ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
#End If

Public Const GHND = &H42
Public Const CF_TEXT = 1
Public Const MAXSIZE = 4096

Function ClipBoard_SetData(MyString As String)
   #If VBA7 Then
      Dim hGlobalMemory As LongPtr, lpGlobalMemory As LongPtr, hClipMemory As LongPtr
   #Else
      Dim hGlobalMemory As Long, lpGlobalMemory As Long, hClipMemory As Long
   #End If
   Dim x As Long
   ' Allocate moveable global memory.
   '-------------------------------------------
   hGlobalMemory = GlobalAlloc(GHND, Len(MyString) + 1)

   ' Lock the block to get a far pointer
   ' to this memory.
   lpGlobalMemory = GlobalLock(hGlobalMemory)

   ' Copy the string to this global memory.
   lpGlobalMemory = lstrcpy(lpGlobalMemory, MyString)

   ' Unlock the memory.
   If GlobalUnlock(hGlobalMemory) <> 0 Then
      MsgBox "Could not unlock memory location. Copy aborted. Please contact 14Fathoms."
      GoTo OutOfHere2
   End If

   ' Open the Clipboard to copy data to.
   If OpenClipboard(0&) = 0 Then
      MsgBox "Could not open the Clipboard. Copy aborted. Please contact 14Fathoms."
      Exit Function
   End If

   ' Clear the Clipboard.
   x = EmptyClipboard()

   ' Copy the data to the Clipboard.
   hClipMemory = SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, hGlobalMemory)

OutOfHere2:

   If CloseClipboard() = 0 Then
      MsgBox "Could not close Clipboard. Please contact 14Fathoms."
   End If

End Function
Sub TestCOPYPASTE()
    Call ClipBoard_SetData("Hello World " & now())
    'Open notepad or in the immediate window and hit control-v
End Sub
```

Comment: your code works! However, i see that though there is some clipboard text present, EmptyClipboard() does not seem to clear the clipboard at all! Any suggestions as to why this is not working on Excel 2016/2019 64 bit versions?

Comment: for e.g.     
    
Sub ClearClipboard()
        Dim x As Long
        Public Const APP_TITLE As String = "API Clipboard Clear"
    
        On Error GoTo ErrorHandler_
    
         OpenClipboard (0&)
         EmptyClipboard
         CloseClipboard
    
         Exit Sub
     ErrorHandler_:
         MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Description, vbCritical, APP_TITLE
     End Sub

Comment: This just worked for me on the same error in Access 2016.  You rock!

Answer (score 3):

I know that this question is now closed, but I prefer this **much** simpler approach, which will work independently of the architecture. And I like the approach of a single function to either read/write the clipboard.

```
Function Clipboard(Optional StoreText As String) As String
'PURPOSE: Read/Write to Clipboard
'Source: ExcelHero.com (Daniel Ferry)

Dim x As Variant
'Store as variant for 64-bit VBA support
  x = StoreText
'Create HTMLFile Object
  With CreateObject("htmlfile")
    With .parentWindow.clipboardData
      Select Case True
        Case Len(StoreText)
          'Write to the clipboard
            .setData "text", x
        Case Else
          'Read from the clipboard (no variable passed through)
            Clipboard = .GetData("text")
      End Select
    End With
  End With
End Function
```

Comment: Wow!!! thank you thank you thank you.  I have just spent about two hours trying to convert 32bit cllipboard api to 64 bit.  many forums have slightlty different declare functions lstrcpyW etc. with various mixes of "as longptr" or "as any" or "as long".  Some seem to work, but I am left with  bad feeling that they might not be exactly right.  And of course they are littered with #if Win64, or vba7 or vba6. Your elegant code works perfectly in window 10 office 2010 32 bit and windows 11 office 365 64 bit office.  And it is

Comment: Glad it helps.  'less is more'

Comment: msg to the person who suggested an edit to the code: adding a msgbox to such a fonction is clearly stupid.

Comment: I have been called worse

Answer (score 0):

Use the code exactly as shown here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192913.aspx

except insert PtrSafe after Declare for all the API declarations.

The code should be in a module by itself.

Like this:

```
Option Explicit

Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalUnlock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As Long) _
   As Long
Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalLock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As Long) _
   As Long
Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalAlloc Lib "kernel32" (ByVal wFlags As Long, _
   ByVal dwBytes As Long) As Long
Declare PtrSafe Function CloseClipboard Lib "User32" () As Long
Declare PtrSafe Function OpenClipboard Lib "User32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) _
   As Long
Declare PtrSafe Function EmptyClipboard Lib "User32" () As Long
Declare PtrSafe Function lstrcpy Lib "kernel32" (ByVal lpString1 As Any, _
   ByVal lpString2 As Any) As Long
Declare PtrSafe Function SetClipboardData Lib "User32" (ByVal wFormat _
   As Long, ByVal hMem As Long) As Long

Public Const GHND = &H42
Public Const CF_TEXT = 1
Public Const MAXSIZE = 4096

Function ClipBoard_SetData(MyString As String)
   Dim hGlobalMemory As Long, lpGlobalMemory As Long
   Dim hClipMemory As Long, X As Long

   ' Allocate moveable global memory.
   '-------------------------------------------
   hGlobalMemory = GlobalAlloc(GHND, Len(MyString) + 1)

   ' Lock the block to get a far pointer
   ' to this memory.
   lpGlobalMemory = GlobalLock(hGlobalMemory)

   ' Copy the string to this global memory.
   lpGlobalMemory = lstrcpy(lpGlobalMemory, MyString)

   ' Unlock the memory.
   If GlobalUnlock(hGlobalMemory) <> 0 Then
      MsgBox "Could not unlock memory location. Copy aborted."
      GoTo OutOfHere2
   End If

   ' Open the Clipboard to copy data to.
   If OpenClipboard(0&) = 0 Then
      MsgBox "Could not open the Clipboard. Copy aborted."
      Exit Function
   End If

   ' Clear the Clipboard.
   X = EmptyClipboard()

   ' Copy the data to the Clipboard.
   hClipMemory = SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, hGlobalMemory)

OutOfHere2:

   If CloseClipboard() = 0 Then
      MsgBox "Could not close Clipboard."
   End If

   End Function
```

Comment: This code does not work in 64-bit Excel 2013.  The kernel32 API declarations aren't LongPtr.  It errors in GlobalUnlock.  My code in the main body of the question does not error and the APIs are declared for 64-bit.  But thanks for trying.