# Put text to clipboard reliably

Tags: vba, outlook, clipboard

I added VBA code to *ThisOutlookSession* to put a mail's subject line and the recipient's name into the mail body. This does not work reliably.

To be variable on where I paste the text, I use a data object of MSforms and it's *PutInClipboard* function to move the generated text to the Windows clipboard.

This works most of the time but sometimes the clipboard only contains two undefined characters. I am sure the text to be inserted was generated correctly.

```
// forClip is a string that contains a text line
Set MyData = New MSForms.DataObject
MyData.Clear
MyData.SetText forClip
MyData.PutInClipboard
// the code ended here but as described the clipboard then contains ��
// I added the following lines only to find out where it all goes wrong

MyData.GetFromClipboard
forClip = MyData.GetText(1) 
// the string going back to "forClip" only contains the two characters mentioned.

Set MyData = Nothing
```

The code works most of the time - but if it fails, it will keep failing.

Could it be, that the clipboard interprets the text not as text but as something different? Is there a way to force it to interpret the data as text?

Comment: I've had problems with that code on Windows 10 - you may need to switch to an API-based method.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18668928/excel-2013-64-bit-vba-clipboard-api-doesnt-work

Comment: Thank you @TimWilliams - this worked very well!